How to Represent Role-Specific Relationships in an ER Diagram?
I’m new to drawing ER diagrams.
In my case, the Staff entity has an attribute called role with values like Head of Department, Dean, and Admin.
The Department entity should only have a relationship with Staff members who have the Head of Department role.
How can I show this in the ER diagram?
Do I need to make each role its own entity?


Welcome to StackOverflow, could you pleas split the image to have one diagram on each?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
